# Parsing Random.org data to an int in JS

Tags: javascript, html

I have [a little web app](http://misc.bhstudios.org/CSS%20Die.htm) I'm using to test out CSS animations. I've got it working but I want more true randomness, so I'm trying to draw from [Random.org](http://www.random.org/integers/?num=1&min=1&max=6&col=1&base=10&format=plain&rnd=new). **How can I take [the result from Random.org](http://www.random.org/integers/?num=1&min=1&max=6&col=1&base=10&format=plain&rnd=new) into a JavaScript variable and use it as an int?**

Comment: Why the downvote? How is this unclear or not useful?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You use `$.ajax` to load the site, then `parseInt(x)` and pass that to a function to handle the randomness.

For example:

```
$.ajax({
    "type": "GET",
    "url": "http://www.random.org/integers/?num=1&min=1&max=6&col=1&base=10&format=plain&rnd=new",
    "success": function( data, status, xhr ){
         send_the_number_to_a_handler( parseInt( data ) );
    }
});
```

Comment: does this require that I make the user download jQuery?

Comment: Technically, yes, but the website you posted already is, so I didn't see a problem.

Comment: Oh... that it does. I gotta keep remembering what I've enabled :P
Thank you :3

Answer (score -1):

What??, **you can generate random number using JavaScript** itself !!

```
function getRandomInt(min, max){
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
}
```

Unless there is a specific need to connect to that website, which I am unable to guess

Secondly,
to understand that, I looked into your code, and found that its way too similar to my friend desandro's [**DEMO**](http://desandro.github.com/3dtransforms/examples/cube-02-show-sides.html) of 3dtransforms

Comment: If you look at the source of the web app, you'll see I'm already doing this. I don't want to, though; I want to use Random.org for more true randomness, as I said in the question.

Comment: @Supuhstar, what is **true randomness** ?? you want only numbers. JavaScript itself can give you random numbers. Even Random.org guys will be smiling by seeing that you are hitting their site just for a random integer :)

Comment: True randomness is randomness that you can't predict. You can easily predict JavaScript's pseudorandom numbers by using the same random number generator and giving it the same seed. Random.org doesn't use a random number generator; it gets its data live from atmospheric variations.

Comment: I don't like being insulted, @OmShankar. This is a programming practice for me, and I plan on extending it for use in real life after I get the basics down.

Comment: @Supuhstar, he he, then u need to start practicing that. Its really a funny thing why u want **true randomness** in a CSS 3 Cube, which has only 6 outcomes, that to copied-from-someone-else CSS 3 demo

Comment: As far as I can tell, the demo you linked isn't the one that I found my original code from, and neither is copyrighted in any way. There's no harm in using it.